# iOS users cannot access web app with SSO

Tags: ios, facebook, html, single-sign-on

Facebook seems to more or less require single-sign on for iOS apps. The downside seems to be that no iOS user can subsequently access the web app. (They are automatically redirected to the iTunes store.)

This means that once you develop a native iPhone app, no iPad user can access a perfectly usable experience on the web, and instead can only use the iPhone version. Facebook itself does not redirect against the user's will to the iPhone version simply because you navigate to Facebook in iOS Safari, so why is this forced on developers and users?

Of course, it's possible our dev team overlooked some workaround, but for the moment, it seems it's impossible for a single Facebook app with multiple clients (native, web) to actually offer users choice as to which type of client they use. Does anyone know otherwise?